# How do i restrict the number to a total of 3 on my input fields?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to restrict the number of input values to only three for my two input fields. Example.. `input 1 = 1, input 2 = 2. so, 1+ 2 = 3 or 2 + 1= 3`, or if the value in one input reach 3, the user will not be able to add more.. there were other similar questions but they are usually only for 1 input field. I want the restriction for the combined field.

I have tried the following code and it does not seem to react the way I want it.. it does not total the value to only 3. It does this in the browser, but when I look at the console, it still continues.

```js
$('.qty_pack').change(function() {
  var i = 0;
  if (i >= 3) {
    $(this).parent().find('.qty_pack').val(0);
    console.log('You have reached max items');
  }
  $('.check_sales_pack').each(function() {
    i += parseFloat($(this).parent().find('.qty_pack').val())
  });
  console.log(i);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="hidden" class="check_sales_pack" name="check_sales_pack">
  <input type="number" class="qty_pack" name="qty_pack" value="0" min="0" max="3">
  <input type="number" class="qty_pack" name="qty_pack" value="0" min="0" max="3">
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if `i > 3` *after* iterating over the inputs and adding to `i`. Also, use the selector `.qty_pack` to select the inputs:

```js
$('.qty_pack').change(function(e) {
  let count = 0;
  $('.qty_pack').each(function() {
    count += parseFloat(this.value);
  });
  console.log('Total:', count);
  if (count > 3) {
    // Reset the *most recently changed* input to 0:
    e.target.value = 0;
    console.log('You have reached max items');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="hidden" class="check_sales_pack" name="check_sales_pack">
  <input type="number" class="qty_pack" name="qty_pack" value="0" min="0" max="3">
  <input type="number" class="qty_pack" name="qty_pack" value="0" min="0" max="3">
</div>
```

Keep in mind that if the calculated count *has* to be correct, verification should be done on the server as well, when the data gets sent to it - code that runs on the client cannot be trusted, because the client can run (and monkeypatch) any code they want.

Comment: Just a quick note: I have a feeling that OP is using `.parent()` because there might be multiple groups of `.qty_pack` on the same page. In that case, it might be safer to use `$(this).parent().find('.qty_pack').each(...)` :)

Comment: you are correct.. i am looking at adding more .qty_pack field.. will it affect what CertainPerformance showed.. ?

Comment: @CertainPerformance.. i found an issue.. when the total number reaches 3, when i click on it reverts back to 0, because that is what is declares here "e.target.value = 0;".. wouldnt it be nice to revert it to previuos number preior to the click? Say input 1 = 1, input 2 = 2, then when i continue to click, it should not revert to 0 but to the previous number.

Comment: @RichardRosario It would be moderately more complicated - for that functionality, you'd have to save the last value used for each input on every change. Probably use a Map to associate inputs to their last values. Unfortunately, you can't just revert the inputted value with `preventDefault` or something like that

Comment: @CertainPerformance, I have been thinking about what you said really hard and I have come up with something.. I added a container for the previous value as an attribute of the input[name=qty_pack], then use that to get the value of previous click.. it worked pretty good.. thanks for the guide. now the value revert back to the previous total..